# How to install python libraries from GitHub onto PyCharm?

Tags: python, github, pycharm

I am just learning how to use GitHub, I want to download a python library to get the latest exchange rate between two currencies and I found one on GitHub. How would I download it and use it on pycharm?

Comment: Is it not available anywhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is even a slightly popular library, it should have a PyPi page. Check the documentation or the README for any mention of

```
pip install <package_name>
```

If the above is not an option, then try this
The repository link is probably something like:

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git
```

For this, open a terminal and run

```
pip install https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/archive/master.zip
```

Replace username and repo from the URL.

Example:
For pandas, the URL is: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas
Running

```
pip install https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/arhcive/master.zip
```

should install pandas onto my system, but in the above case, as mentioned running `pip install pandas` should be enough as pandas is already published onto PyPi